# AutoFilter to find blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply an autofilter in VBA for three different criterias in the same field. Once I have applied the filter I would like to find all those cells that are blank, can anyone advise?

```
    Sub ApplyAutoFiler()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim I, j, NumberOfErrors As Long
    IsErrors = False

    Set ws = Sheets("Assessments")

    NumberOfErrors = 0
    Dim Z As Range
    Set Z = Cells(4, 3).EntireColumn.Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not Z Is Nothing Then
        NumberOfRows = Z.Row
    End If

    For I = 4 To NumberOfRows

   With ws
   .AutoFilterMode = False
  .Range("W4:AA4").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("A", "B", "C"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
  .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535
  .AutoFilterMode = False

   End With

   Next I


   End Sub
```

[image]

I ended up doing this as a nested if statement

```
If Range("W" & i).Value = "A" Or Range("W" & i).Value = "B" Or Range("W" & i).Value = "C" Then
     If Range("AD" & i).Value = "" Then
        Range("AD" & CStr(i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        NumberOfErrors = NumberOfErrors + 1
     End If
  End If
```

Comment: What is `I` in your `Cells(I,J)`... at the moment it equals to Zero which causes an error...

Comment: I, Is the row number
J, Is the column 
They are both set as Long

Comment: About how many rows does NumberOfRows evaluate to?  There is a limitation of around 8k non-contiguous cells when using SpecialCells.  If it's more than that, you may want to use a loop.  Also, do you just want to check column AA for blank cells or any cells in columns W through AA?

Comment: At the minute it's only checking 580 but this can change to at least a 1000+. 

I am filtering on column W and I only want to check those in AA for blanks.

Comment: Let me come back to you on this. Thanks for the screenshot. Makes it much clearer.

Comment: Just saw your comments in the below post. Please confirm this : You want to check for blank cells in Col AA for every a,b,c in Col W

Comment: I want to check all blank cells in column AA when column W is filter on a, b and c.

Comment: Updated my post with both NON VBA and VBA Mehtods.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to get me close (it also assumes you have a worksheet called "Assessments"):

```
   Sub ApplyAutoFiler()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Sheets("Assessments")

 With ws
      .AutoFilterMode = False
      .Range("A:AZ").AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=Array("a", "b", "c"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
      .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535
      .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You, This seems to be doing something but every time I try and run it the spreadsheet does not respond

Comment: Can you expand on what "does not respond" means?  Does it lock up, or nothing happens? If I had to guess, without seeing your sheet, this part should be cleaned up "Range("A:AZ")." to be only the rows you actually want filtered.

Comment: It locks up and I have to go onto task manager to close it down. 
I changed the range for only the rows I needed and the filter is working but then locks again

Comment: It sounds like you have other things going on (like a lot of calculations).  Can you provide a sense of what else is going on in the sheet that may be causing the problem?  Maybe try my code on a new sheet just to make sure it's not the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: I did try it on a new sheet, and I could see the filter work but after that it locked.
 what I also meant to include was that the blanks I am looking for are in a different column, sorry I am new to vba.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out why your sheet is locking up.  I'm not having that issue on my end.  Can you post a sample on a file sharing site so I can take a look?   This line:

 .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 65535

will highlight in yellow all of the cells in your filtered range that are blank.

Comment: I am getting an error stating SpecialCells out of Range, I'm not sure if it is because there is a lot of empty cells on the sheet, I only wish to see if there are it column AA. 

I have updated my coding.

Answer (score 1):

Something I just discovered today about filtering for blanks using VBA code.  Be sure to include this in ALL code where you need to have blank cells:

```vb
' Get Rows with blanks
WorkRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=" & ""

' Hides Rows with blanks ... same idea with the "<>" for operator
WorkRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>" & ""
```

The first criteria gets true blank cells and those cells with hidden/non-printable characters, the 2nd criteria gets those cells containing an empty string.  Excel user-interface handles this nicely, but VBA code requires both criteria.

This undocumented caveat just cost me several hours of debugging, not to mention a few choice words from my manager about "I thought we were removing the blanks from these columns..."

Just thought I would share, in the hopes of saving you all some headaches.

Comment: Headache successfully avoided!

Answer (score 1):

I know this treads had been quite long. But just want to share. To filter out blank cells, you could use autofilter using the following criteria:

```
Worksheets("sheet name").Range("A1").autoFilter Field:=18, Criteria1:=(Blanks)
```

"Field" refers to the column numbers. As for "Criteria1", it can be either

```
Criteria1:=(Blanks)
```

or

```
Criteria1:="="
```

or

```
Criteria1:=""
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for this. You can use Conditional Formatting for this. See this example

In the CF rule, set this formula

`=AND($AA5="",OR($W5="a",$W5="b",$W5="c"))`

**ScreenShot**

[image]

If you still want VBA then see this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim blnkRange As Range, rng As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Assessments")

    With ws
        '~~> Sample range for testing purpose
        Set rng = .Range("W4:AA11")

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With rng
            '~~> Filter on "a","b","c"
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("a", "b", "c"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
            '~~> Then filter on blanks on Col AA
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="

            '~~> Using offset. Assuming that Row 4 has headers
            Set blnkRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> This will give you the blank cells in Col AA
    If Not blnkRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each aCell In blnkRange
            '~~> Color the blank cells red in Col AA
            If aCell.Column = 27 Then aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The blanks I am trying to find are in a different column. column W will never be blank, it's column AA that could be.

Comment: I will be happy to amend the above code if you show me an example?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of how the data could be, does this make it clearer?

Comment: Thanks for helping, unfortunately I am getting run-time error '5' on this line: 
Set blankRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells and I can't seem to figure out the problem

Comment: What have you set for `Set rng = .Range("W4:AA11")`?

Comment: It was set as .Range("W4:AA4"), I also tried looping through the rows again and using NumberOfRows.

Comment: Change AA4 to the AA<LastCell> where <LastCell> is the last row which has data in Col AA

Comment: The problem with that is the Last Cell could possible change, that's why I tried to loop through each row to find the number of rows.

Comment: You don't need to loop to find the last row of AA. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: Ahh thanks, that has helped. However now I can't get the filter to work.